# libuv fs read file print one more time

Tags: c, libuv

Recently I am writing some c code to simply read file and print out content using libuv.
But I don't know why my code would print first buffer twice.

```
void open_cb(uv_fs_t* open_req){
    int r = 0;
    if(open_req -> result < 0 ) printf("open_req");

    context_t* context = open_req -> data;

    size_t buf_len = sizeof(char) * BUF_SIZE;
    char *buf = malloc(buf_len);
    context->iov = uv_buf_init(buf, buf_len);
    context->times = 0;

    uv_fs_t *read_req = malloc(sizeof(uv_fs_t));
    context->read_req = read_req;
    read_req->data = context;
    r = uv_fs_read(uv_default_loop(), read_req, open_req->result, &context->iov, 1, 0, read_cb);    
}
void read_cb(uv_fs_t* read_req){
    int r = 0;

    //uv_fs_t* close_req = mollac(sizeof(uv_fs_t));
    if(read_req->result < 0){
        printf("read_req");
        return;
    }else if(read_req->result == 0){
        printf("read finish\n");
        return;
    }

    context_t* context = read_req->data;

    printf("%zu %zu", read_req->result, context->read_open_req->result);
    printf("%i :", context->times);
    printf("%s\n", context->iov.base);

    size_t buf_len = sizeof(char) * BUF_SIZE;
    char *buf = malloc(buf_len);
    context->iov = uv_buf_init(buf, buf_len);
    context->times++;
    read_req->data = context;

    r = uv_fs_read(uv_default_loop(), read_req, context->read_open_req->result, &context->iov, 1, -1, read_cb);
    if(r<0) printf("read_req");
}
```

I am reading this file with only one line text: "hello1234567\n", 
the buffer size is 5 so it would print 5 characters per time.
However the result is

```
read result:5, open result:10
time: 0 :hello
read result:5, open result:10
time: 1 :hello
read result:5, open result:10
time: 2 :12345
read result:3, open result:10
time: 3 :67

read finish
```

first number is read_req->result, second number is context->read_open_req->result.

Other codes are similar to the [official tutorial](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/filesystem.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out my stupid mistake.
`r = uv_fs_read(uv_default_loop(), read_req, open_req->result, &context->iov, 1, 0, read_cb);`
The params offset should be -1 instead of 0 to read from prev offset.